# Rails Regex Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Any Regex gurus out there?  I have a position_id that is a string and can have the following formats.  The number of digits can very, but is sort-of like so.  all digits or digits and one dash '-'.

```
123456  or
123456-123
```

I need a regular expression that says, if position_id is not in that/those formats, throw a flag.  I thought I had it with the following, but it doesn't seem to work.  maybe my syntax is wrong.

```
if !params[:position_id] =~ /^\d+-?\d+$/
  flash[:error] = "error message here"
end
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should work as long as you have at least 2 digits numbers. I guess you're testing it with 1 digits one?

If so, this should do it :

```
flash[:error] = "error message here" unless params[:position_id] =~ /^\d+(-\d+)?$/
```

We're making the whole `-123` optional there

Comment: actually, I'm testing with asdfsadfdsaf just to see if I can any error message back.  Users should not be able to enter any non-digit characters other than the '-'.  Should be just digits and maybe one dash.

Comment: generally speaking hyphens should be escaped

Comment: Hmmm all of the answers given work in the console. just not my controller.  Grrrr!  Thanks for the help though

Comment: Then I'd log somewhere `params[:position_id]` to see if it's actually what you think it is!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one:

```
^([0-9]*)(\-[0-9]*)?$
```

http://rubular.com/r/2qSTHIPEo9

If you expect the number range to be a certain length just change it up as so:

```
^([0-9]{6})(\-[0-9]{3,4})?$
```

which says in words:

- "any number thats 6 digits long"
- "if there is a hyphen the second number must be between 3 and 4 digits"

http://rubular.com/r/5SHiJ1GKiK

**EDIT:** -- to answer the comment below

```
if !params[:position_id].match(/^([0-9]{6})(\-[0-9]{3,4})?$/)
    flash[:error] = "not valid"
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-match

Comment: I changed the code to just /\d/ and it won't catch on that with no digits.  I test for params[:position_id].blank? so I know I have the param showing.  Never had so much trouble on an easy regex.